# Relative path readFile error ENOENT: no such file

Tags: javascript, node.js, relative-path

I have a server file which sends out emails to user based on the `restify` API I have built. That file is under `/lib` directory. And when that file `mail_helper.js` tries to read the file `./email_templates/default-inline.html` it fails. It is trying to find `email_template` file from the `root` of the node app instead of inside `lib` directory. The folder structure looks like this:

```
- root
   - package.json
   - index.js (requires lib/mail_helper.js)
   - lib
      - mail_helper.js (reads file ./email_templates/default-inline.html)
      - email_templates
         - default-inline.html
```

Running `node index.js` from the root directory throws the error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my-local-path\root\email-templates\default-inline.html'

How can I reference relative path properly to avoid this situation?

Comment: Don't use a relative path,  use something like >  `path.join(__dirname, 'email_templates', 'default-inline.html')`  a relative path only makes sense on your require calls, not when passing filenames about.

Comment: @Keith That worked! But I have put that many places. Can you please add some code in answer and explain what __dirname does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Keith,

Relative path should be written like this:

```
path.join(__dirname, 'email_templates', 'default-inline.html')
```

This, worked and fix all of my errors after replacing this at all the places in my module.